# How to create a custom meta table in wordpress?

Tags: wordpress

I have custom meta box with multiple fields and it is working fine. Now, I want to store this meta box data into a custom table. So how can I do that ?

I have researched on google and Youtube but didn't got what exactly I am looking for.

If anyone can provide me with Step by Step guide or tutorial links then it will be very much helpful.

Comment: Why do you want to store it in a custom meta table? That actually makes no sense.  A custom meta box (presumably for a page or post) should store it's data in the postmeta table, which WordPress has all the functions in place to make that super simple.  There is literally NO reason to create a custom meta table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the official Wordpress guide: https://developer.wordpress.org/plugins/metadata/custom-meta-boxes/

Comment: That does not answer the question.  The question is about creating a custom meta _database table_, not _meta boxes_.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure *why* you would want to store Post Meta into a separate table, but I've had situations where I've needed to do crazier things.

The gist would be that you can use your [Custom Meta Box](https://developer.wordpress.org/plugins/metadata/custom-meta-boxes/) to display the form fields, and then handle those form fields with your own custom function on the [`save_post`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/save_post) hook.

Let's say you've registered a custom meta box with `<input name="my_custom_table_field" />` in it. Instead of using [`update_post_meta()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/update_post_meta) on the `save_post` hooks, you could write a function that manages the data with the [`$wpdb->update`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wpdb/update/) method. Something like this would get you started:

```
add_action( 'save_post', 'save_my_custom_data' );
function save_my_custom_data( $post_id ){
    global $wpdb;

    if( isset( $_POST['my_custom_table_field'] ){
        $result = $wpdb->update(
            'my_custom_table',
            array(
                'post_id' => $post_id,
                'my_custom_table_field' => $_POST['my_custom_table_field'],
            ),
            array(
                'post_id' => $post_id
            ),
            array(
                '%d',
                '%s'
            ),
            array (
                '%d'
            )
        );
    });
}
```

You'll want to make sure to handle the data appropriately before saving it, of course. And again, I'm not sure *why* you'd need a custom "meta" table, but farbeit from me to say you "shouldn't" (especially depending on your particular usecase) - but something like the above would get you started.

To summarize:

- Display your custom meta box with WP's metabox functions
- Handle the `save_post` hook for your custom fields separately
- Sanitize, trim, or otherwise make sure the data being stored is supposed to be stored in accordance to best practices for the field type
- Make use of the global `$wpdb` class to update it.

Also of note, this answer doesn't go into CREATING the database table - because that depends on your storage engine, particular indexing needs, etc. But in general you should be able to search for "create database table in [whatever storage language]" to get a walkthrough of creating the table - then use the outline above to store the data in it.

Comment: How we can create more than one custom tables and relate them as we do in a normalised MySQL?

Comment: It sounds like you'd want to ask your own question. But in order to relate them, just add a `post_id` column to your other tables. Then when you save the post, just save the `$post_id` to that custom table as well. When fetching the data, you can just `JOIN`, `UNION`, whatever you need, based on the `post_id` column matching.